# showing out of the box custom properties tab for terms in termstore in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, term-store, term, term-set

We want to capture additional metadata for each Term (Ex: Requested for, Requested date, Requested by). These properties are not available in SharePoint 2010 OOTB but can be achieved using `Term.SetCustomProperty()` programmatically. Where as in SharePoint 2013, we have option to add/update/delete custom Properties in Term Store management window (Custom propertiesTabs), which is OOTB (shown in the image below).

[image: Custom properties for a term in term set (sharepoint 2013)]

Is there anyway to achieve the same using any out of the box features in SharePoint 2010? If not can you please suggest any robust way to achieve the same requirement.

Thanks.